# How to change the supervision timeout of BLE peripheral?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, bluetooth-gatt

I have a pure C application running on a BLE peripheral that reproduces some of the bluez code.

In le_set_advertising_parameters_cp, I see min_interval and max_interval but I don't see any supervision timeout field.

```
typedef struct {
    uint16_t    min_interval;
    uint16_t    max_interval;
    uint8_t     advtype;
    uint8_t     own_bdaddr_type;
    uint8_t     direct_bdaddr_type;
    bdaddr_t    direct_bdaddr;
    uint8_t     chan_map;
    uint8_t     filter;
} __attribute__ ((packed)) le_set_advertising_parameters_cp;
```

Is there another advertising parameters (extended???) that features supervision timeout?

I'm aware of the following code in hcitool:

```
hci_write_link_supervision_timeout(device_handle, htobs(cr->conn_info->handle), timeout, 1000);
```

But in my own code, I don't manage to get the handle of the central device once the connection has been established - I'm also wondering whether if it's not too late to change supervision timeout after the connection.

```
ioctl(device_handle, HCIGETCONNINFO, (unsigned long) cr);
```

fails with a "no such file or directory" error though I'm sure that the central device is connected.

I have also tried to play with:

```
/sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/supervision_timeout
```

but it has no effect.

How can I change from user-space the supervision timeout?

Comment: It is the central that in the end decides the connection parameters, including supervision timeout. The interval you set when advertising is just the advertising interval. The peripheral can suggest new connection parameters to the central though, but it's out of my knowledge how to do that with bluez.

Comment: Yes, I know that the peripheral SUGGESTS value to the central which decides. Actually, it's possible to have a back and forth possible between the central and the peripheral and then central decides indeed. My question is how can I suggest supervision timeout from user-space bluez?